# Change the color of an individual node

Tags: javascript, treemap, echarts

is it possible to change an individual node's colour in an eChart treemap? I tried assigning a color property but the color does not change. I've gotten the label to change but i want the overall background color

I have tried by having a color property under series-treemap.data as the documentation says https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-treemap.data.color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the [documentation](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-treemap.data.color), `series-treemap.data.color` is a **list** that affects the color of the nodes from the same level (and their children).
If you want to specifically set a node's color, you'll have to use `series-treemap.data.itemStyle.color` ([doc](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-treemap.data.itemStyle.color)).

Here is an example:

```js
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

option = {
  series: [
    {
      type: 'treemap',
      data: [
        {
          name: 'nodeA',
          value: 10,
          color: ['blue','green', 'grey'],
          children: [
            {
              name: 'nodeAa',
              value: 4,
              itemStyle : {
                color: 'red'
              },
            },
            {
              name: 'nodeAb',
              value: 6,
              children: [
                {
                  name: 'nodeAb1',
                  value: 20
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              name: 'nodeAc',
              value: 6
            },
            {
              name: 'nodeAd',
              value: 6
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name: 'nodeB',
          value: 20,
          color: ['orange'],
          children: [
            {
              name: 'nodeBa',
              value: 20,
              children: [
                {
                  name: 'nodeBa1',
                  value: 20
                },
                {
                  name: 'nodeBa2',
                  value: 20
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

myChart .setOption(option)
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.3.2/echarts.min.js"></script>
    <div id="main" style="width: 600px; height:400px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

All the childrens of `nodeA` (ie. `nodeAb`, `nodeAc`, `nodeAd`) follow the rule set by `color: ['blue','green', 'grey']`. But `nodeAa` doesn't follow this rule because `itemStyle.color` has its own value set to `red`.

Nodes `nodeBa1` and `nodeBa2` are both orange because it's the only color in their parent's color list. If you want one of them to have a different color, add more colors in the `color` list, or simply set `itemStyle.color`.